# Sharepoint 2010 Integration with Exchange/Outlook

Tags: calendar, office-integration, outlook, exchange-server

I have a shared calendar in sharepoint 2010 site which also manages users' schedules.
I want to display the schedule of all users in one sharepoint shared calendar in such a way that the users' schedules from outlook/exchange calendars are imported to their respective rows of shared calendar.

The calendar overlay function allows only 10 exchange calendars to be overlaid and they are not overlaid to respective user's calendar (I think), which does not fulfill my need.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few other commercial solutions that addresses SharePoint calendaring & scheduling needs - [Bamboo Solutions' Calendaring product](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/toolkit_calendaring.aspx) and [Virto Ajax Calendar](http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint-web-part-calendar-ajax.aspx).

CAVEAT: I do not work for the above companies.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Group Calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-group-calendar-HA101810606.aspx) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create new calendar in SharePoint, next add into Outlook (this is not best solution, but you can add this calendar in any Outlook).
You must remember that user will have two calendars. Own and from ShraPoint.